# Is there a word or a term for when a story's ending is very similar or the same as its beginning?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

In the novel Perfume, by Patrick Süskind, it is notable that the main character appears in the same setting and scenario in the beginning of the novel and in the end. Is there a word for when this happens in novel or TV shows?

Comment: Did he thus *come full circle*?

Comment: no. There is a certain character development, but he comes back to the place of his birth, where he also dies.

Answer (score 2):

This is called *bookending* or the *bookends technique*.  One explanation is at [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/way_6140862_bookends-technique.html)  This technique is also used in speaking.  See [Andrew Dlugan's speaking blog](http://sixminutes.dlugan.com/bookending-speech-definition/) for a good article.  I try to use this technique whenever possible when I write a speech, especially motivational/inspirational speeches.

*Bookending* is a form of a *callback*.  A *callback* is when some part of a story, speech, etc., refers back to something earlier.